# What does "$1/*" mean in "for file in $1/*"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The short bash script below list all files and dirs in given directory and its sub. What does the `$1/*` mean in the script? Please give me some references about it. Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh

list_alldir(){
    for file in $1/*
    do
        if [ -d $file ]; then
            echo $file
            list_alldir $file
        else
            echo $file
        fi
    done
}   

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then 
    list_alldir "$1"
else
    list_alldir "."
fi
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the glob of the first argument considered as a directory

In bash scripts the arguments to a file are passed into the script as `$0` ( which is the script name ), then `$1`, `$2`, `$3` ... To access all of them you either use their label or you use one of the group constructs. For group constructs there are `$*` and `$@`. (`$*` considers all of the arguments as one block where as `$@` considers them delimited by `$IFS`)

Answer (score 4):

`$1` means the first parameter.
`for file in $1/*` means loop with the variable `file` having the value of the name of each file in the directory named in the first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

$1 is the first commandline argument. If you run ./asdf.sh a b c d e, then $1 will be a, $2 will be b, etc. In shells with functions, $1 may serve as the first function parameter, and so forth.