# How to read arguments from bash

Tags: bash

I am curious as to how to pass in arguments via terminal to the bash script and read them and process the script functions based on the arguments.

So if I did something like:

```
./scriptname.sh install
#or
./scriptname.sh assets install
```

How would I say, ok the first argument installs something, while the second sais to do something else based on the first argument.

Comment: Use `$1` for instance. You can check for the existence by doing `if [ -z $1]; then echo "You didn't enter any arguments." fi`

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: Btw, I'm sure you get many results if you google for "bash script command line arguments" or something similar. No offense, but this is *easily* searchable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$0 is the name of the command
$1 first parameter
$2 second parameter
$3 third parameter etc. etc
$# total number of parameters

 for args in $* 

   blah blah
```

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason not to, always prefer `"$@"` (with quotes) over `$*` or `$@`

Comment: Just to get all of the variables in one place: `$$` gives process ID of the shell, `$!` gives the process ID of most recently executed background process, `$?` gives the last exit status, `$_` gives the absolute filename of the current script

Answer (score 2):

One great way to pass arguments to a script is to use the bash builtin functionality `getopts`

you can use it like this:

```
# a script that accepts -h -a <argument> -b
while getopts "ha:b" OPTION
do 
   case $OPTION in
       h)
         # if -h, print help function and exit
         helpFunction
         exit 0
         ;;
       a)
         # -a requires an argument (because of ":" in the definition) so:
         myScriptVariable=$OPTARG
         ;;
       b)
         # do something special
         doSomeThingSpecial
         ;;
       ?)
         echo "ERROR: unknonw options!! ABORT!!"
         helpFunction
         exit -1
         ;;
     esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a particular argument with `$1`, `$2`, ... See eg [What does "$1/*" mean in "for file in $1/*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778017/what-does-1-mean-in-for-file-in-1)

You can also use `"$@"` to loop on your arguments. Ex : https://github.com/gturri/dotfiles/blob/master/bootstrap.sh#L64