# Bash Function Won't Complete

Tags: bash, sorting, apt

I am trying to sort the output of apt-cache search.  Here is what I have currently;

```
sch ()   
{  
   apt-cache search $1  
   sort -nr  
}
```

When I run this it works but will not return me to the command prompt so I can type another command.

Can anyone complete this or show me a better way.  TIA.

Comment: What exactly do you see when it "stops"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sch(){
    apt-cache search "$1" | sort -nr
}
```

You missed quotes and pipe `|`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That fixed it. Can you clarify what "$1" is doing here please, is it considered a loop or argument? EDIT: [from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778017/what-does-1-mean-in-for-file-in-1) ::In shells with functions, $1 may serve as the first function parameter, and so forth

Comment: It is simply the first argument of your function